# Nextjs - How to preload images on website launch before even getting to the page where they 're displayed?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, loading

I'm using nextjs for an website that has a gallery, I'd like to start preloading all the assets from the gallery as soon as we get onto the page but doesn't seem to find how to do this.
I have tried to hide a link to the gallery in the layout, the HEAD, the first page but it doesn't seem to work.
I am using the nextjs Image component but don't find it so powerful in the image optimization but perhaps I am doing it wrong.

Please help

```
const GalleryUnit = ({ publicId, openRecap }) => {
  const galleryUnitRef = useRef();
  const placeholderSrc = assetPath(publicId, "jpg", 1);
  const src = assetPath(publicId, "jpg", 100);

  return (
    <motion.div
      variants={unitAnim}
      ref={galleryUnitRef}
      className="galleryUnit relative"
      onClick={openRecap}
    >
      <Image
        src={src}
        placeholder={placeholderSrc}
        alt="Lia's art"
        fill
        sizes="100%"
      />
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`priority`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#priority) property on the `Image`.

> When true, the image will be considered high priority and preload. Lazy loading is automatically disabled for images using `priority`.

For example:

```
const GalleryUnit = ({ publicId, openRecap }) => {
  const galleryUnitRef = useRef();
  const placeholderSrc = assetPath(publicId, "jpg", 1);
  const src = assetPath(publicId, "jpg", 100);

  return (
    <motion.div
      variants={unitAnim}
      ref={galleryUnitRef}
      className="galleryUnit relative"
      onClick={openRecap}
    >
      <Image
        src={src}
        placeholder={placeholderSrc}
        alt="Lia's art"
        fill
        sizes="100%"
        priority
      />
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```